# How to sort recyclerview items (my items here are text files) by month

Tags: android, sorting, android-recyclerview, collections, timestamp

Text files are taken from the internal storage. I wanted to sort these files by month.

```
public ArrayList<File> findtext (File file)
{
    ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    File[] files = file.listFiles();

    for (File singlefile : files)
    {
        if (singlefile.isDirectory() && !singlefile.isHidden())
        {
        arrayList.addAll(findtext(singlefile));
        }
        else
        {
            if (singlefile.getName().endsWith(".txt"))
            {
                arrayList.add(singlefile);
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

Done lot of research but only found solution to sort the items byDate, I want to sort the items by month.